# Angularjs disable button if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a button on a form that I'd like to disable until one or more checkboxes have been selected. This is probably fairly simple to solve, but the button is not disabled when I use !result.isSelected.

This is my button:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="send()"  ng-disabled="!result.isSelected" </button>
```

And the checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" ng-model="result.isSelected" ng-click="selected()" />
```

Does anyone know of a better solution? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What selected() in the ng-click do actually?

Comment: It selects the checkbox to add the items to an array.

Answer (score 9):

A better solution would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-row" ng-model="checked" ng-click="selected()" />

<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="send()"  ng-disabled="!checked"> </button>
```

Comment: Welcome.This was fairly a very simple issue you were facing. Please go through this documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled
 If it still doesnt help. you are always welcome on stackoverflow.

Comment: Will do :).. just needed to understand why it wasn't working the way I had it.